# Как сделать ширину div по содержимому?

Tags: веб-программирование, html, вёрстка, css

И заодно отцентрировать его - 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RqCH/)

div — item-list

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QQwH4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Контейтеру text-align: center, у самого элемента уберите ширину.

http://jsfiddle.net/wC3qp/

Comment: Спасибо! Как сделать выравнивание по левому краю?
http://i.imgur.com/VLn71My.png

Comment: Не работает. Ширина дива больше ширины содержимого.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно в три ряда, то попробуйте сделать [так](http://jsfiddle.net/wC3qp/1/).

Comment: @NoName, cпасибо, хочется 4 ряда, резиновые и по середине, но при ресайзе окна чтобы равнялись по левому краю. Никак не получается

Comment: решите задачу - покажите). А вообще, может пригодиться - http://masonry.desandro.com/. Автоподстройка под размер экрана. На странице есть множество примеров (н-р: http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/), где блоки переносятся влево, но расположены относительно центра.

Answer (score 0):

```
.css-selector {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Это я сделал первым делом, не работает